# In a SQL server, passwords are hashed in chinese. What algorithm it might be using?

Tags: mysql, microsoft

While performing the following query, passwords are displayed in Chinese. I'm wondering what hashing algorithm is being used here in order for me to carry out a brute-force attack.[image: first line is the query and the second line is the result]

Comment: While you see some chinese characters you also see other stuff - this is more like some binary string which for some reason is treated as UTF-8 or similar. Binary by itself does not indicate a specific hash algorithm. In other words: too few information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Computing a hash is a math operation on binary data. It produces a fixed size array of bytes, depending on the algorithm. It doesn’t produce characters.

What you’re seeing is encoded output. The SQL utility you’re using has decided to output the byte array as some form of Unicode. Instead, you need to change the output encoding of your SQL so you can view the data in a way that makes sense to you.

If you’re using Microsoft TSQL, you could look at a function like `master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr` to output the data in hexadecimal.